# Как записать большой CLOB в таблицу? Ошибка: String literal too long

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, хранимые-процедуры

Есть процедура, которая записывает данные в таблицу.

Пример процедуры:

```
procedure pSave(sRefer in varchar2,
                cMsgQueue in clob) is
                
begin
  insert into table1 (REFER, MSG)
               values(sRefer, cMsgQueue);
end;
```

В значении параметра `cMsgQueue`  передается `CLOB`, у которого кол-во символов 204017 (размер).

При запуске процедуры получаю ошибку:

> string literal too long

Как можно записать большой `CLOB` в таблицу одним `sRefer`?

Если передавать маленькие куски, то процедура отрабатывает без ошибки.

Comment: тип данных MSG  - clob

Comment: Вы что-то не договариваете, [всё работает](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e920fb1548e3ca1102c908da25af5c32).

Comment: Оказывается через оракловый тест скрипт не получиться дергать процедуру передавая большие данные. А так clob принимает , спасибо

Comment: Ну да, проблема не в процедуре или clob, а как и в ошибке сказано, в литерале, который вы пытаетесь записать, и он не может быть очень длинным. Литерала для clob, что-то типа `clob'very long input'`, не существует.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обе ошибки, в SQL и PL/SQL соответственно:

> ORA-01704: string literal too long
> PLS-00172: string literal too long

Говорят о превышении лимита для символьного литерала, то есть колличества символов (ед.изм. в байтах) между одиночными кавычками `''`  (обычно 4000 в SQL и 32767 в PL/SQL).

Ошибка возникает при инициализации параметра для передачи в процедуру символьным литералом с превышением длины, то есть до того, как процедура собственно будет вызвана.

Возможные решения, добавлять в `CLOB` по частям, либо процедурой `dbms_lob.append`, либо конкантенацией:

```
declare 
    c clob := '123';
begin
    for i in 1..3 loop
        dbms_lob.append (c, rpad ('A', 32767, 'A')); end loop; 
    pSave ('ref1', c);
end;
/
declare
    longstring1 varchar2 (32767) := 'AAA<всего 32767 символов>AAA';
    longstring2 varchar2 (32767) := 'AAA<всего 32767 символов>AAA';
begin 
    pSave ('ref2', longstring1||longstring2); 
end;
/
```

Небольшой обзор, что работает, а что нет, на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7b4e6c877f529cd02f5e809d8bc667ca).

**Следует учесть**, что инструменты могут накладывать свои ограничения на длину вводимых литералов. Например, SQL*Plus считает, что и 3000 уже достаточно:

```
$ sqlplus -l user/pass@server/db1 <<EOF
declare var varchar(32767) := '$(printf 'A%.0s' {1..4000})'; begin null; end;
/
EOF

SQL> SP2-0341:
line overflow during variable substitution (>3000 characters at line 1)
```